# EC2 metric and incoming connections?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to monitor a certain number of incoming connections and when it exceeds more than x IP addresses, I would like to start an existing server (autostart).
How can I do this with EC2?

Comment: How do you define an "incoming connection"? Incoming to an application? Concurrent sessions? Sessions per time period?

Comment: total number of IPs connected to 1 particular application. Could also just be total number of IPs but I'd have to think about icmp, internal dns and others.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with EC2 metrics alone. The closest you could get would be to use the [`NetworkIn` CloudWatch metric](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/ec2-metricscollected.html#ec2-metrics) to trigger the second server.

Here are some other solutions that might work:

- Use an Elastic Load Balancer (ELB) and use the [`ActiveConnectionCount` CloudWatch metric](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/elb-metricscollected.html) to scale out
- Use Kinesis to stream the request IPs and either do analytics on the data in real time to scale out or create a custom CloudWatch metric to handle the scaling.

Comment: ok, so if I have multiple vpn servers behid the load balancer. The clent connect to load balancer xxx.xxx.xxx.1 and it redirect them to one of the many vpn servers. That will work without any setup on the vpns behind the LB?

Comment: and is it one connection per IP address on ActiveConnectCount or multiple like 1 in, 1 out, 1 icmp, 1 http, etc.

Comment: Yes, to the first question - no VPC change would be needed. And the ActiveConnectiontionCount is not per IP but rather per request. So it could be multiple connections from the same public IP.

Comment: what can I use to say number of users connected > x? then spawn new server

Comment: Use the ELB's `ActiveConnectionCount` CloudWatch metric to trigger an increase in an EC2 Autoscaling Group.

Comment: ActiveCOnnectionCount is ALL connections. I just need the number of IP addresses connected on a port not the total requests